# Close mobile menu on click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, responsive-design

I'm designing a responsive site that can be viewed [**here**](http://bauerarchive.com/test) and using jQuery slimMenu to provide a collapsible navigation menu that initializes at a specific break point. I would like to force the menu to re-collapse after a user clicks a link, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do so. I found [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262118/jquery-mobile-menu-to-close-after-i-click-a-menu-item) which addresses a similar question by suggesting the creation of an additional click event to prompt the menu to close.

Thus, I figured I could wrap the function in another that checks to see if the responsive menu has been triggered as follows:

```
// collapse slimmenu on click
$(window).resize(function(){    
    if ($(".menu-collapser").css("display") == "block" ){
        $(".nav").on("click", "li", function () {
        $(".collapse-button").click();
        });
    }
});
```

There is clearly some kind of error in my code as it's creating funky behavior in Firefox by causing the collapsed/responsive menu to collapse and open several times before finally closing, or not closing at all in Chrome. What am I doing wrong here? Or is there an entirely different approach to force the menu to close after click that would be preferable to this one? Thanks for any assistance here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(window).resize() is really sensitive, so setting an event listener in $(window).resize() is not advisable. Because event listener is set many times.

You should set the event listener outside for once, this is how I would do that,

```
// collapse slimmenu on click
$(window).resize(function(){    
    if ($(".menu-collapser").css("display") == "block" ){
        $(".nav").addClass("mobile");
    } else {
        $(".nav").removeClass("mobile")
    }
}).resize();

$("body").on("click", ".mobile li", function () {
  $(".collapse-button").click();
});
```

**Updated:** Sorry, I shared wrong code with you, if you set $(".mobile").on() that is not actually set because there isn't any element with the mobile class on init time.

So you should handle body click `on(".mobile li")` that would solve the problem.

And one more thing, don't forget to trigger resize on document.ready if somebody opens your website in a mobile phone, mobile class will never be set, because there isn't a resize event on startup.

Comment: thanks for your response; I'm trying your approach and it doesn't seem to be working for some reason. I can see in Firebug that the "mobile" class is being added, but the click function doesn't seem to be having an effect. I'm wondering if there's some other issue in my util.js file? (I've updated my site with your code so can see.)

Comment: Hi ocanal I'm realizing the other solution is problematic and I'm trying to implement yours, but it's still giving me issues. I'm hoping you could check out my updated link above and see what might be causing the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Ah got it, that makes sense; thanks much, I'll give it a go. As for your point about document.ready: I'm using a bunch of jQuery plugins on this site, and I've just grouped all the initializations within a jQuery document ready function in my util.js file-- is there anything wrong with this approach? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

it appears your problem can be easily solved. because your menu is collapsed after a menu click you don't need to check for anything. it is a simple bind event to the li of a .nav element.

```
$(".nav li").on("click", function(){
        $(".collapse-button").click();
    }
});
```

This is of course assuming you're click() function does a close